# Qt QFRAME cutting off bottom of drawn circle

Tags: qt

I am using Qt 4.7.4 and drawing a circle inside a QFRAME. No matter what size I make the QFRAME the bottom of my circle is clipped off.:

[image]

Code is really basic and the Qframe has no special properties set, default other than colors palette.

I am instantiating MyFrame in MainWindow Constructor:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    MyFrame* foo = new MyFrame(ui->Frame); // Frame is just a Frame widget dropped in from Qt Designer on the mainWindow
}
```

SubClassed QFRAME Constructor:

```
class MyFrame : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyFrame(QWidget *parent):
    QFrame(parent)
{

    int w = parent->width();    // width of QFRAME
    int h = parent->height();   // height of QFRAME

    if (w == h)
    {
        Diam = w;
    }
    else if (h < w)
    {
        // Adjust diameter for smaller height
        Diam = h;
    }
    else
    {
        // Adjust diameter for smaller width
        Diam = w;
    }

    maxRadius = Diam/2 ; // Maximize circle diamater inside QFRAME

    centrePt = QPoint(w/2, h/2);
   }
```

MyFrame Paint Event :

```
    void MyFrame::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QFrame::paintEvent(event);
       QPainter painter(this);
       QBrush fillStuff = QBrush(myColor, Qt::SolidPattern);
       painter.setPen(myColor);
       painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
       painter.setBrush(fillStuff);
       painter.drawEllipse(centrePt, maxRadius, maxRadius);

       return;
}
```

Does this have something to do with the viewport?

Comment: Please post all relevant code. It's so hard to understand what you do here. Where did you place all this code? in constructor? in resize event? Also QPainter.drawEllipse not fills ellipse with color as you show here. Why you have margins? The ellipse should be painted close to borders as to your code, not as you show.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have 4.8 but anyway I see several problems in your code. First of all you cannot base your painting on parent's size. What will be size of MyFrame in your case? Ajust MyFrame size directly or through layouts and so calculate painting canvas based on MyFrame size not parent size. Also, setting size in constructor is not good idea. Size can be changed and you will get incorrect result. Move all your calculation in `paintEvent`. All this bunch of code in constructor you can replace with `Diam = qMin(w,h);`.  `return` statement is unnecessary here since you return nothing.